# can we update query of firestore recycler adapter without setting the whole adapter again?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using firestore recycler adapter to populate my documents in a recycler view like below. it is working fine. How can I update the query?

```
    query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("partners").orderBy("mCompanyName").limit(limitValue);

    options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PartnerInfoPojo>()
            .setQuery(query, PartnerInfoPojo.class).build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PartnerInfoPojo, PartnersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final PartnersViewHolder holder, int position, final PartnerInfoPojo model) {
            Logger.v("onBindViewHolder ....." + position);

        }

        @Override
        public PartnersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.single_partner_row1, group, false);
            return new PartnersViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            Logger.v("on Data changed");
        }
    };
    mPartnerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the query, you are using this:

```
  query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("partners").orderBy("mCompanyName").limit(limitValue);
```

and then using the variable `query` in `setQuery`, the only way to update the query is to change it example:

```
query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("partners").orderBy("mCompanyName").equalTo(name);
```

But if you mean update the data.. then just update the data before in another activity maybe then in this activity you will get the updated data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around to refresh firestore recycler adapter.
before changing your Query do this.

```
adapter.stopListening();
```

Now change your Query as you per your requirement
and set your adapter. Now set adapter to start listening again.

```
adapter.startListening();
```